# Ranking and sorting on Array/List

Tags: java, array, unit-testing

My apology, I am quite new to posting a question in this forum.

I had a task where I was supposed to write a solution to sort entries(Name, score - in an array/list) in order of score and generate ranking based on higher score to lower scores.

I tried doing that, code is working what it was supposed to do but it seems very ambiguous and tightly coupled, I can't even write a unit test for it.

Could someone have a look and suggest do I need to minimize and simplify this class so that I can write a Unit Test class for this.

> I have pasted main method class, If anyone wants me to paste other
>   relevent classes as well so do ask me please.

Any suggestion(s)/workaround(s) would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

```
public class JournalAnalyzer {
    final static int LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL = 5; //Length Journal array
    static int count = 0;
    static Integer ranking = 1;
    static Journal[] journals = new Journal[LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL];
    static ArrayList<Journal> list = new ArrayList<Journal>();
    static Object[] scoreList = new Object[LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL];
    static String journalName;
    static Double journalScore;
    static Integer journalRank;
    static Boolean journalReview;

private static void initData(Journal[] journals) {
    journals[0] = new Journal(0, "Journal A", 5.6, false);
    journals[1] = new Journal(0, "Journal B", 2.6, false);
    journals[2] = new Journal(0, "Journal C", 3.2, false);
    journals[3] = new Journal(0, "Journal D", 4.1, false);
    journals[4] = new Journal(0, "Journal E", 1.6, false);
}

private static int fillJournalList(int count, Journal[] journals,
        int LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL, ArrayList<Journal> list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL; i++) {
        journalRank = new Integer(journals[i].getRank());
        journalName = new String(journals[i].getJournal());
        journalScore = new Double(journals[i].getScore());
        journalReview = new Boolean(journals[i].getIsReviewed());

        if (!journalReview) {
            Journal value = new Journal(journalRank, journalName,
                    journalScore, journalReview);
            list.add(value);
            count++;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static void GenerateRanking(Integer ranking, int count,
        ArrayList<Journal> list, Object[] scoreList) {
    Double scoreComparatorOne;
    Double scoreComparatorTwo;

    Comparator<Journal> scores = new SortScore();
    Collections.sort(list, scores);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        if (i == 0) {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        } else {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i - 1)).getScore();
        }
        if (scoreComparatorOne.equals(scoreComparatorTwo)) {
            if (ranking == 0) {
                ranking += 1;
            } else {
                ranking = ranking;
            }
        } else {
            ranking = i + 1;
        }

        (list.get(i)).setRank(ranking);
        scoreList[i] = (list.get(i));

    }
}

private static void displayJournal(int counter, Object[] scoreList) {
    JournalOutput printer = new JournalOutput();
    printer.display(count, scoreList);
    System.exit(0);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    initData(journals);
    count = fillJournalList(count, journals, LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL, list);
    GenerateRanking(ranking, count, list, scoreList);
    displayJournal(count, scoreList);
}
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array sort-rank class](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/array-sort-rank-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you are using `static` for everything.  Change all of the static variables to instance variables, and all of the static methods (apart from `main`) into instance methods.  Then have your `main` method create an instance of `JournalAnalyzer` and call the (now instance) methods on that instance.

That will make the code more testable.  Another thing you need to do to improve testability is to make the methods you want to test `public`.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Stephen, it helped me alot and I've written the test case for it as well.