# Array sort-rank class

Tags: java

I had a task where I was supposed to write a solution to sort entries(Name, score - in an array/list) in order of score and generate ranking based on higher score to lower scores.

I tried doing that, code is working what it was supposed to do but it seems very ambiguous and tightly coupled, I can't even write a unit test for it.

Could someone have a look and suggest.

I have pasted main method class, If anyone wants me to paste other relevent classes as well so do ask me please.

Any suggestion(s)/workaround(s) would be much appreciated.

```
public class JournalAnalyzer {
    final static int LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL = 5; //Length Journal array
    static int count = 0;
    static Integer ranking = 1;
    static Journal[] journals = new Journal[LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL];
    static ArrayList<Journal> list = new ArrayList<Journal>();
    static Object[] scoreList = new Object[LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL];
    static String journalName;
    static Double journalScore;
    static Integer journalRank;
    static Boolean journalReview;

private static void initData(Journal[] journals) {
    journals[0] = new Journal(0, "Journal A", 5.6, false);
    journals[1] = new Journal(0, "Journal B", 2.6, false);
    journals[2] = new Journal(0, "Journal C", 3.2, false);
    journals[3] = new Journal(0, "Journal D", 4.1, false);
    journals[4] = new Journal(0, "Journal E", 1.6, false);
}

private static int fillJournalList(int count, Journal[] journals,
        int LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL, ArrayList<Journal> list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL; i++) {
        journalRank = new Integer(journals[i].getRank());
        journalName = new String(journals[i].getJournal());
        journalScore = new Double(journals[i].getScore());
        journalReview = new Boolean(journals[i].getIsReviewed());

        if (!journalReview) {
            Journal value = new Journal(journalRank, journalName,
                    journalScore, journalReview);
            list.add(value);
            count++;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static void GenerateRanking(Integer ranking, int count,
        ArrayList<Journal> list, Object[] scoreList) {
    Double scoreComparatorOne;
    Double scoreComparatorTwo;

    Comparator<Journal> scores = new SortScore();
    Collections.sort(list, scores);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        if (i == 0) {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        } else {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i - 1)).getScore();
        }
        if (scoreComparatorOne.equals(scoreComparatorTwo)) {
            if (ranking == 0) {
                ranking += 1;
            } else {
                ranking = ranking;
            }
        } else {
            ranking = i + 1;
        }

        (list.get(i)).setRank(ranking);
        scoreList[i] = (list.get(i));

    }
}

private static void displayJournal(int counter, Object[] scoreList) {
    JournalOutput printer = new JournalOutput();
    printer.display(count, scoreList);
    System.exit(0);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    initData(journals);
    count = fillJournalList(count, journals, LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL, list);
    GenerateRanking(ranking, count, list, scoreList);
    displayJournal(count, scoreList);
}
}
```

My question is how to minimize and simplify this code so that I can easily write a unit test for this class

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to minimize and simplify this code so that I can easily write a unit test for this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        if (i == 0) {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        } else {
            scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i - 1)).getScore();
        }
        if (scoreComparatorOne.equals(scoreComparatorTwo)) {
            if (ranking == 0) {
                ranking += 1;
            } else {
                ranking = ranking;
            }
        } else {
            ranking = i + 1;
        }
    (list.get(i)).setRank(ranking);
    scoreList[i] = (list.get(i));
 }
```

Theres no need to verify all the time this conditional:

```
if (i == 0) {
                scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i)).getScore();
            } else {
                scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i - 1)).getScore();
            }
```

inside the loop. Since `i` it will be equal to 0 only once.

Modifying  to:

```
...
Double scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(0)).getScore();
Double scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(0)).getScore();
ranking = getRating(scoreComparatorOne,scoreComparatorTwo,ranking,0);
(list.get(0)).setRank(ranking);
scoreList[0] = (list.get(0));

for (int i = 1; i < count; i++){
        scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore();
        scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i - 1)).getScore();
        ranking = getRating(scoreComparatorOne,scoreComparatorTwo,ranking,i);
        (list.get(i)).setRank(ranking);
        scoreList[i] = (list.get(i));
}
```

where `getRating` is:

```
 public Integer getRating (Double sCOne, Double sCTwo, Integer ranking, int i)
    {
           if(sCOne.equals(sCTwo))
              return (ranking == 0) ? 1 : ranking;
           else return i + 1;
    }
```

also you can turn your `fillJournalList` into (but this is not a major problem):

```
private static int fillJournalList(Journal[] journals,
    int LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL, ArrayList<Journal> list) {

for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_JOURNAL; i++){

    if (!journals[i].getIsReviewed())
        list.add(new Journal(new Integer(journals[i].getRank(),                  
                              new String(journals[i].getJournal(),
                              new Double(journals[i].getScore(), 
                              false);

return list.size();
```

}

This way you only create the new Objects when you will insert them. Not in every for iteration. With the above modification there no need to this:

```
public class JournalAnalyzer {
    ...
    static String journalName;
    static Double journalScore;
    static Integer journalRank;
    static Boolean journalReview;
```

You can remove all four variables.

Comment: Hi,

I made changes to the code, now its throwing NullPointerException.
Due to scoreList skipping to fill scorelist[0] element.

Comment: @AliJay did you manage to solve?

Comment: @@dreamcrash I have made changes like mentioned in my last comment, now its throwing NullPointerException. Due to scoreList skipping to fill scorelist[0] element. And it is due to GenerateRanking method where for loop starts from counter 1.

Comment: post your code here http://codepaste.net/ and post it back the link here so i can see it

Comment: here you go <http://codepaste.net/87imtg>
Cheers

Comment: If you want me to paste other relevant classes, do let me know please.
Many thanks

Comment: ranking = getRating(scoreComparatorOne, scoreComparatorTwo, ranking, 0); put zero not i

Comment: another thing just put scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore(); inside the loop as well

Comment: Still the same, it's throwing NullException because of journals[0] is null, method starts filling in from [1] element.
Any idea?

Comment: put this out side         (list.get(0)).setRank(ranking);
        scoreList[o] = (list.get(o)); right before the loop

Comment: Thanks, it works now but it not generating ranking as it should be, it generates 1st rank same if the scores are same, 
but on 2nd rank it continues till 5.
For instance:
Scores [5.6,5.6,3.2,3.2,1.5]
Ranks  [1,1,2,3,4,5]
Where it should been like this:
Scores [5.6,5.6,3.2,3.2,1.5]
Ranks  [1,1,2,2,5]

Comment: Are you sure that in yours original code the rating were working? (I just edit my rating method but is not that different

Comment: Yes it's still working when I run my previous class.

Comment: Strange send me the code that works and the code that is not working codepaste.net

Comment: Working code before modification: http://codepaste.net/m31k46
Code after modification: http://codepaste.net/n9ih9d

Comment: You have to add  scoreComparatorOne = (list.get(i)).getScore(); inside the loop also, and it is scoreComparatorTwo = (list.get(i-1)).getScore();. Please see the method I had put here is different than you had put it

Comment: Like this http://codepaste.net/a1tr45

Comment: Yes thanks, I figured it out before your last comment.
But a full heap thanks to you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AliJay You welcome, glap it helps you. I just don't know why I lots the points I earn on this question when it was on StackOverFlow, maybe it was due to the migration.